# React pass from parent to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass data in React from parent to child , I already managed to set right value from one file to another, but same that information that I passed I need to pass once more again. I will show you some code so you can understand actual problem.

From List.js file I'm taking the right information like

```
<Products categoryid={item.id}/>
```

so that same item.id I passed to Products, as you see I have this.props.categoryid which is giving me right information as value to add this item as you see, and it looks like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { getProducts, addItem, deleteItem, updateItem } from './ProductFunctions'


class Products extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            id: '',
            title: '',
            price: '',
            off_price: '',
            category_id: '',
            arttitle: '',
            artbody: '',
            editDisabled: false,
            items: []
        }
this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getAll()
    }

    onChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value

        })
    }

    getAll = () => {
        getProducts().then(data => {
            this.setState(
                {
                    title: '',
                    price: '',
                    off_price: '',
                    category_id: this.props.categoryid,
                    items: [...data]
                },
                () => {
                    console.log(this.state.items)
                }
            )
        })
    }
```

So the real problem is how to pass this this.props.categoryid as a category_id to getProducts function in ProductFunctions.js so I can get list from ?

```
export const getProducts = category_id => {
    return axios
        .get('/api/products/${category_id}', {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        })
        .then(res => {
            return res.data
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forgot to use `` and instead used '' in the `getProducts` function in `ProductFunctions.js`, so let's correct that.

```
export const getProducts = category_id => {
  return axios
    .get(`/api/products/${category_id}`, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
    .then(res => {
      return res.data;
    });
};
```

Now, just pass the `categoryid` you obtained from `props` to the `getProducts` in the `getAll` method, when its invoked. (As per what the exported function expects in `ProductFunctions.js`

```
getAll = () => {
  const { categoryid } = this.props;
  getProducts(categoryid).then(data => {
    this.setState(
      {
        title: "",
        price: "",
        off_price: "",
        category_id: categoryid,
        items: [...data]
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.items);
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: Consider accepting an answer which best fit your problem.

Comment: I am confused to find the answer downvoted when the OP confirmed it to be a working solution?

Answer (score 0):

Access the prop within `getAll` function

```
getAll = () => {
  getProducts(this.props.categoryid).then(data => {
    this.setState({
        title: '',
        price: '',
        off_price: '',
        category_id: this.props.categoryid,
        items: [...data]
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.items)
      }
    )
  })
}
```